# How to create a numpy list from within a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy list of arrays (a two-dimensional list):

```
db = [ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6, ch7, ch8, ch9, ch10, ch11, ch12, ch13, ch14, ch15, ch16]
```

I would like to perform some operations in these arrays like this:

```
for i in db:
    newch = (eegFilter(i)/sens)+25
```

How can I create a new two-dimensional list with the results of each loop iteration so that the new array would look something like this:

```
[[newch_iteration_1], [newch_iteration_2], [newch_iteration_3], ....]
```

Comment: Lists and arrays are very different things. A list of arrays is not a two-dimensional list, and neither a list of arrays nor a 2D list is what you should be using, which is a 2D array. If you're using NumPy, you want to avoid using lists to hold or work with numbers. What are you actually using to store your data?

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  the python script reads the data from a csv file and then stores it in a 2D list to manipulate it. is this not the most efficient way. the data files are usually very big (hundreds of megs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[((eegFilter(i)/sens)+25).reshape(1, *i.shape) for i in db]
```

**Demo:**

```
In [12]: db = [np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5), np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)]

In [13]: [(x%2).reshape(1, *x.shape) for x in db]                                                
Out[13]: 
[array([[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],                                                                        
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]]),                                                                      
 array([[[0, 1, 0, 1],                                                                           
        [0, 1, 0, 1],                                                                            
        [0, 1, 0, 1]]])]
```